# Android call retrofit with one parameter optional

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to do a call like this:

```
/api/basket/info?id={value}-{extra}$&id={value2}
```

Sending for the moment the values like this:

```
@GET("/api/basket/info") 
fun getInfo(@Query("id") value: List<String>)
```

And my problem is how i can pass the "extra" separated with "-" in the query with value "id".

Here is when i calling the api.

```
    fun getBagInfo(value: List<String>? = null, extra:List<String>? = null){

      val response = api.getBagInfo(value).execute()   }
```

Comment: please provide few samples of request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect You have method from which You communicate with api. I've used java but You can convert it to Kotlin.

```
public Call<Object> getBasketInfo(int value1, int[] extraValues, int value2) {
    if (extraValues.length == 0) {
        getBasketInfo(String.valueOf(value1), String.valueOf(value2));
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer in : extraValues) {
            sb.append("-").append(in);
        }
        getBasketInfo(value1 + sb.toString(), value2 + ""));
    }
}
```

It will call:

```
/api/basket/info?id=1&id=3
/api/basket/info?id=1-2&id=3
/api/basket/info?id=1-2-3&id=3
```

Comment: I update the code , but the problem is that is a list and can have for example 15 values

Comment: @dddddrrrrrr updated, pass only one String value constructed by StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the easiest option in your case will be using POST instead of GET. Do you have opportunity to change the server api?
The issue is that backend won't accept list of ids in get request. Because it hase method like `request.getParameter(id)`. Backend doesn't know which id.